# Is it possible to acess a css class ::after and ::before selectors through Hostbinding?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically set a `'background-color'` property on my component `host::after` and `host::before` based on a value in an object through hostbinding.

I haven't tried a whole lot since i don't know if this is even possible, if it is i would think the syntax would look somthing like this:

```
@HostBinding('style.after') after;
@HostBinding('style::after') after;

:host {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}


:host::before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 300%;
    height: 300%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-top: -100%;
    border-radius: 45px;
    /*background-color: should be inserted by hostbinding;*/
    animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
}

:host::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background-color: should be inserted by hostbinding*/
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -.4s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css custom properties

> They are set using custom property notation (e.g., --main-color:
>   black;) and are accessed using the var() function

```
    :host{
       --primary-color: red;
      --secondary-color: green;
     }
    :host::before {
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 300%;
        height: 300%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: -100%;
        margin-top: -100%;
        border-radius: 45px;
        background-color:var( --primary-color);
        animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
    }

    :host::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*background-color: should be inserted by hostbinding*/
       background-color:var( --secondary-color);
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -.4s 
        infinite;
    }
```

Then use hostbinding to change the background color dynamically. Use DomSanitizer api to prevent unsafe style value error.

```
@HostBinding('style') style;
  constructor(private element:ElementRef,private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){

  }
  changeColor(){
    this.style = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--primary-color: blue;--secondary-color: green;');
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-style-host

[Check this for more about DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

[More About CSS Variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Comment: How do i change both `--primary-color` and `--secondary-color`?